# How to copy all code from existing bitbucket repo to a new repo in bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

I have an android project in a bitbucket Repo (lets call it repo A).
I have to create a new android application which is quite similar to old android application and further modifications. For this new android application, I want a new bitbucket repo.
I have created a new bitbucket repo (lets call it repo B)
At the moment repo B is empty.
Now I want to copy all the code files of repo A to repo B. So that I can do further android development in repo B.
During all this process, I want to keep repo A intact.

Please advice how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible approaches here.

If you want Repo B to be able to receive future updates from Repo A, then it's easiest to [fork Repo A](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/forking-a-repository-221449527.html). Repo B will then have its own permissions, CI/CD setup, and so forth, but Repo B will start as a full clone of Repo A and you'll be able to sync any new changes between the two as necessary.

If you don't want that, then you can push whatever code you want from anywhere up to repoB. It might be easiest to do something like this on your local system:

```
cp -rp repoA repoB
cd repoB
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:owner/repoB.git
```

Comment: Hi Jim
Once repo A files are copied to repo B, I don't need any link between the two repos. The development in repo B should be committed and pushed to repo B only. Similarly, any further development in repo A will remain in repo A.

In your commands, you are setting remote url for the repo. Will it upload(push) all files to bitbucket repo B? I think, it won't. 
So what should I do to achieve it? Please advise